# Is there any way to send an email in the same thread?

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, gmail-api

I'm trying to send emails into one thread so it looks as similar as possible as sending via Gmail web UI.

According to the Gmail [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads#adding_drafts_and_messages_to_threads), I wrote the next code on Kotlin that works correctly, but not completely

```
val DEFAULT_CHARSET: String = Charsets.UTF_8.name()

// get headers from original email
val messageId = originalMessage.payload.headers.find { it.name.equals("Message-ID", true) }?.value
val subject = originalMessage.payload.headers.find { it.name.equals("Subject", true) }?.value

// creating message
val message = MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(Properties()))

message.setFrom(InternetAddress(emailFrom, senderNameFrom, DEFAULT_CHARSET))
message.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress(emailTo))

message.setSubject(subject, DEFAULT_CHARSET)

// this headers are required accoring to [RFC 2822][1] standard
message.setHeader("In-Reply-To", messageId)
message.setHeader("References", messageId)
message.setHeader("Subject", "Re:$subject")

// creates message part
val messageBodyPart = MimeBodyPart()
messageBodyPart.setContent(content, "text/html; charset=UTF-8")

// creates multi-part
val multipart = MimeMultipart()
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart)


// sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
message.setContent(multipart)

val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream()
emailMessage.writeTo(buffer)
val requestMessage = Message()
requestMessage.raw = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(buffer.toByteArray())

// this thread ID you should collect from the original message
requestMessage.threadId = threadId

// from the result variable you can collect id, threadId, labels, etc.
val result = gmail.users().messages().send("me", requestMessage).execute()
```

As a result, emails send into one thread (inbox looks like this), but there are no three dots "show trimmed content" that hides the content of previous messages:
[image: What I have]

Is it possible to make it looks like?
[image: What I need]
Other languages and libraries will also suit me.

P.S. I also tried sending emails as a Gmail draft, but this also doesn't work.

Test was done with java-libraries:

- javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01
- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:1.6.2

Comment: Oh so when you say "thread" you don't mean `java.lang.Thread`.

Comment: See [Threading changes in Gmail conversation view](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html) for the conditions needed for messages to be threaded together.

Comment: Some guy on the internet also said that you should set the reply `References:` field to the message ID as well as `In-Reply-To:`

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the article, now I'm sure that code is correct but it still doesn't work as I want.
@markspace, thanks, I checked one more time, in the current example `message.setHeader("References", references ?: messageId)` references is always equals to `null` for the second email in the thread (first reply)

Comment: Try this lib: https://github.com/mimecast/robin/blob/master/doc/client.md (Disclosure: I'm the author)

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is a bit old, but I stumbled myself in this same problem and managed to make it work.

First thing, you need to set a `Message-ID` header in the MimeMessage object, in the exact format Gmail is expecting ("<anyidyouwant@domain.com>", including the angular brackets). If you don't set this header to the proper format, Gmail will override its value with a new one and store the original value in the `X-Google-Original-Message-ID` header.

That being said, I also had a small issue with the MimeMessage class overriding the `Message-ID` header value when the message was sent, which required me to implement my own extended class, as described [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#msgid).

This is how my Java implementation looks like:

```java
public class MyMessage extends MimeMessage {

    public MyMessage(Session session) { 
        super(session);
    }

    protected void updateMessageID() throws MessagingException {
        setHeader("Message-ID", "<exampleid-myemail@gmail.com>");
    }
}
```